# Retrofit : Only one HTTP method is allowed. Found: GET and GET

Tags: android, http, get, retrofit

I use Retrofit to get data from RestApi to my application in Android.
I have a problem with Get method with parameter. 
When I run my code I get RetrofitError: [...]: Only one HTTP method is allowed. Found: GET and GET.

myWebService:

```
@GET("/tag/{id}")
    void getById(@Path("id") int id, Callback<Data> pResponse);
```

MainActivity:

```
String url = "xyz";
        retrofit = new RestAdapter.Builder()
                .setEndpoint(url)
                .setLogLevel(RestAdapter.LogLevel.FULL)
                .build();
        myWebService = retrofit.create(MyWebService.class);
```

```
myWebService.getById(id, new Callback<Data>() {

                @Override
                public void success(Data data, Response response) {
                    Log.d(CLASS_TAG, data.toString());

                }

                @Override
                public void failure(RetrofitError error) {

                }
            });
```

For example: when i changed `@GET("/tag/{id}")` to `@GET("/tag/1")` everything works well.

Comment: You'll need to take `Call<Data>` as return type and remove **Callback parameter** from method.

Comment: Are you using Retrofit 2 or 1.9

Answer (score 0):

Check you backend for Authorization filter :
you might have authorized the route `/tag/`but you also should authorize `/tag/*` to match the path with parameters syntax.

Please tell us about you backend so we can give you more inputs if needed.